# QuickSort with Random Pivot

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am trying to implement a version of QuickSort with a random pivot selected by generating the random numbers with the boundaries low to high and taking the median of them.

However the code runs extremly slow when I do this. If I try to sort an array with 29 elements it works withing 2 seconds but as soon as I increase the size to 30+ including (30) the algorithm runs extremly slow. Sorting the array with 30 elements takes about 10sec+ and if I go any higher well you get the idea.

This is not the issue if I have a fixed pivot point. I can sort an array with the size of 100 000 without any problems.

I don't know what's wrong and need some help to figure out why it is running so slow when I am generating a random pivot point.

Regards!

```
protected int Partition(int[] v, int low, int high, boolean FixedPivot)
{
    int pivot = 0;
    if(!FixedPivot)
        pivot = RandomPivot(v, low, high); //If I pick a random pivot point then it runs extremly slow for some reason.
    else
        pivot = FixedPivot(v, low, high); //This one works fine, I can sort quickly without any problem.

    int i = low - 1;
    int j = high + 1;
    while(true)
    {
        do j--; while(v[j] > pivot);
        do i++; while(v[i] < pivot);
        if(i < j)
            Swap(v, i, j);
        else
            return j;
    }
}
protected int FixedPivot(int[] v, int low, int high)
{
    int average = (low + high) / 2;
    return Math.max(Math.min(v[low], v[average]), Math.min(Math.max(v[low], v[average]), v[high]));
}
protected int RandomPivot(int[] v, int low, int high)
{
    int X = 0;
    int Y = 0;
    int Z = 0;
    Random random = new Random();
    int range = (high - low) + low;
    if(range > 0)
    {
        X = random.nextInt(range);
        Y = random.nextInt(range);
        Z = random.nextInt(range);
    }
    return Math.max(Math.min(v[X], v[Y]), Math.min(Math.max(v[X], v[Y]), v[Z]));
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like `X` is guaranteed to be above `low`.  Also, why do you even have `Y` and `Z`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that `random.nextInt(range);` is between `0` and `high` and you want it to be between `low` and `high`. Here's how to fix it:

```
int range = (high - low);
if(range > 0)
{
    X = random.nextInt(range) + low;
    Y = random.nextInt(range) + low;
    Z = random.nextInt(range) + low;
}
```